# nuget archive file cannot be size 0

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

we added some libraries for our project then i can't see from solution (Manage Nuget Packages for Solution)

I find a workaround but it didn't fix.

http://hoolihan.net/blog-tim/2012/03/13/strange-nuget-error/

[image: Manage Nuget Packages for Solution]

Edit : I found 0 kb package in packages folder said like above link comment. You probably get 0 kb package from your source control.

Answer (score 2):

Rename the **\package** directory and restore packages from **Packages Manager**.